# make static pattern prerequisites problem

Tags: makefile

Recently, I am working on GNU Make.So I wrote such a file:

```
SOURCE_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJECT_FILES := $(SOURCE_FILES:src/%.c=dist/%.o)

all: ${OBJECT_FILES}
    cc -o main $?

${OBJECT_FILES} : dist/%.o : src/*.c
    cc -c $? -o $@
```

But I got the error below:

```
cc -c src/demo.c src/main.c -o dist/demo.o
cc -c src/demo.c src/main.c -o dist/main.o
cc -o main dist/demo.o dist/main.o
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'dist/demo.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'dist/main.o'
clang: error: no input files
```

My question is, now that, the target is individual for target static pattern matching.
Why the $? refer to all the prerequisites?
How to get the prerequisites for individual target in static pattern matching？

Comment: As an aside, `cc -o main $?` will compile into `main` only the files which changed since the previous run. You want `$^`

Comment: Usually object files are the result of compilation of one single source file. Are you sure you don't want `${OBJECT_FILES} : dist/%.o : src/%.c` instead of `${OBJECT_FILES} : dist/%.o : src/*.c`? And then `cc -c $< -o $@`?

Comment: yeah, you are right, I find I made a mistake using the * symbol instead of %. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the $< special automaic variable.
That works!